# Prorate metered plan in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

We're looking to charge per user in our SaaS. We're using Stripe as our payment processor. The first 5 members are included as part of the base plan. Any excess users are charged an extra free (let's say $10).

If a user is added halfway through the billing period, we'd only want to charge them $5. If they're added 3/4 of the way, they should be charged $7.50. If a user is added for 1/3 of the month and then deleted, they should be charged $3.33.

This is similar to [Slack's approach](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218915077):

> Add new members to a paid workspace If you’re on a paid plan and add
>   new members partway through the billing cycle, we’ll only charge for
>   the cost of the time used. We’ll keep track of this for you, and bill
>   you at the end of each month.
>
> Here’s an example:
>
> Let’s suppose your workspace is on the Standard plan paying monthly,
>   which costs $8 per member per month. You add a new member 10 days into
>   your billing period, leaving 20 days remaining in the month.
>
> The prorated subscription cost is calculated by dividing the cost per
>   member ($8) by the number of days in the month (30) and multiplying it
>   by the number of days remaining (20), which gives us the prorated
>   subscription cost for the remainder of that billing period: $5.33
>
> If you pay annually, it works the same way. We'll calculate the
>   prorated cost for the rest of the year, and bill you at the end of the
>   month for any new additions.

I was wondering if that could be achieved in Stripe.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short Answer

I see some misunderstanding about what Stripe's metered plans are intended for. They stand for a kind of complete action or some work done, such as if your service created some content or performed some other work. In this case, it doesn't matter at which point of the billing cycle the work is performed and that doesn't affect its cost.

Stripe doesn't allow prorating for metered usage at the time I'm writing this comment. So if the usage of something has been logged to Stripe using a metered price, doesn't matter at which point of a billing cycle, it can either be removed without being billed (using `clear_usage: true` when removing a corresponding `SubscriptionItem`) or it will be billed in full at the end of the billing cycle.

#### Detailed Answer

We were facing the same issue and here's how we eventually designed and implemented our billing (simplified for readability).

In our application, we use multi-price subscriptions, where some products represent "Plans" while others represent "Add-Ons".

Let's assume your users can add "Members" and the number of members is limited for each "Plan".

The products in Stripe that define the "Plans" are as simple as:

1. `Product` Hobby (5 members, metadata: `{ type: plan, tier: hobby }`)

   - `Price` Monthly $99/mo
2. `Product` Agency (20 members, metadata: `{ type: plan, tier: agency }`)

   - `Price` Monthly $299/mo
3. `Product` Enterprise (100 members, metadata: `{ type: plan, tier: enterprise }`)

   - `Price` Monthly $999/mo

The products that represent the "Add-On", such as:

- `Product` Team Members (metadata: `{ type: add-on }`)

  - `Price` none (let's assume Hobby-tier users can't add extra members)
  - `Price` Seat (Agency) (metadata: `{ tier: agency }`)
  - `Price` Seat (Enterprise) (metadata: `{ tier: enterprise }`)

> Note
>
> You can see "Plan" products have just one price, while "Add-On"
> products have multiple prices, one for each tier. The `type` and
> `tier` metadata helps you to match "Plans" and suitable "Add-Ons" in
> the back-end.

These "Add-Ons" can use the Graduated model. For example, if your Agency "Plan" includes 20 seats, and then you want to charge $10 per seat per month, your Team Members `Price` for the Agency tier would look like this:
[image]

When creating a subscription it includes two prices:

1. `Product` Agency

   - `Price` Monthly $299/mo
2. `Product` Team Members

   - `Price` Seat (Agency)

In the application, you can have a slider or a text field (GitHub way) where users can add/remove additional seats. If a user adds one more member on the 1st day of the billing cycle and removes it halfway through, Stripe (depending on the subscription settings) will automatically prorate this and charge $5 instead of $10. This way it is possible to change the number of seats on demand and users pay only for the used amount of time. You can also adjust the quantity yourself (Slack way) when the user adds/removes members. All you need to do is to update the quantity on the `SubscriptionItem`. Stripe will do the rest.

The important part to understand is that this logic has to be implemented in your application. When a user removes a member or a member becomes inactive (what Slack does) you should update the subscription and change the quantity. Once the member becomes active the quantity has to be adjusted again. **It is possible to configure the subscription in Stripe and provide the behavior, whether to invoice immediately or at the end of the billing cycle** (the user will receive a detailed invoice for extra cost). Considering the Slack behavior and to avoid lots of invoices being initiated, the second option is preferable.

In case the user wants to upgrade, let's say to Enterprise, you will need to update the subscription accordingly, and change the price for both "Plan" and "Add-On". This is done by updating `SubscriptionItems` and replacing the price ID on them. Stripe will do the rest of the work for you.

In case of downgrade, let's say to Hobby, where the user doesn't have the option to buy extra seats, you will need to remove the `Add-On` from the subscription by removing the corresponding `SubscriptionItem`. And again, Stripe will do all prorations for you and the user will be billed for the usage appropriately.

> More About Metered
>
> We also use metered "Add-Ons" in a similar way, with several
> "included" operations, and then bill using different models, such as
> graduated, package, and volume. Since proration doesn't apply
> and we don't want to generate unnecessary invoices in the middle, if a
> user downgrades to a tier where "Add-On" is not available, we remove
> it from our subscription in the back-end but keep it in the
> subscription in Stripe till the end of the billing cycle. This way
> "Add-On" becomes unavailable to the user in our application but we
> preserve the usage until it's paid. When the billing cycle shifts,
> Stripe charges for the logged usage, resets it, and then we can remove
> those leftover Add-Ons from the subscription in Stripe (using webhook
> notifications).

Comment: I liked the idea of not removing the metered price from the stripe side until the end of the period and just removing it from our internal subscription in our db and letting the stripe calculate the metered billing usage at the end of the month, but then which stripe webhook event you mean to clean up the Stripe side subscription and remove the metered price? `customer.subscription.updated`? don't you think it will be a huge number of calls to handle when the cycle changes?

Comment: Hi @Mohamad, we use subscription.update and check the period changes. Whenever this occurs, we trigger an internal event and, amongst others, it runs a job to remove add-ons that are no longer in the subscription.

Comment: that is a brilliant idea! using the period change in that event! this way we will have a relatively bigger load when the period changes but then we will free ourselves from calculating the prorata for the usage-based prices in the middle of the month! thanks. it helped our team.

Answer (score -2):

Yep!  Stripe will automatically pro-rate when you add users and you can use Graduated Pricing to do what you're trying to do around having the first five seats at price x and all of the remaining seats at price y.

It's discussed in more detail here:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/tiers#graduated

Answer (score -2):

Are you adding usage record for each user?

I think it's better to set the `quantity` of the subscription item to the number of users, this way stripe will prorate exactly the way you wanted.

Notice that subscription item quantity is only permitted for plans with `usage_type` set to `license`.

Here is an example of the upcoming invoice when changing the quantity of a subscription item (I changed it after few minutes) :

[image: Invoice with subscription item change]

Comment: This probably won't work well because it will be considered as paying for additional subscription items instead of paying for metered usage